# wamp server 3.0.6 is green but localhost shows blank

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

I have installed the latest wamp server 3.0.6. While running it shows green but in browser localhost:90 does not open (shows blank.) I have changed the port to 90 in apache httpd.conf

Comment: Any hint in the webserver error log? If you view source of the page in your browser, do you see a blank page or a whole bunch of HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to this link in your browser

http://localhost/

this will open localhost in wampserver 3.0.6

Comment: he did not ask how to open the localhost

Answer (score 0):

Click to wamp icon "Apache->httpd-vhosts.conf" then change the "Require local" to "Require all grented" then save the document. restart the wamp server